# REACT NATIVE: Modal temporary closes (flickers) when app is minimized by Menu Button

Tags: react-native

#### Using the react native's official Modal component

Is there any way to prevent the behavior when the modal is open, if i press the menu button of the mobile (built-in one) the modal flickers and closes temporary exposing the background view. Please see the attached url of the GIF for clarification . I am also not sure whether its a default behavior in react native or not.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfujC.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a solution as much as it's guidance. You haven't really given enough detail to help you out properly. Best if you can share the code or setup a reduced test case at https://snack.expo.io that we can fiddle with.

That said, I'm not totally sure. This is an interesting problem, and I'm curious if you'll find a possible solution and it may depend on your implementation details. For instance, is the modal part of the navigation stack (react-navigation?) or is it an imported component? Either way, I would begin by playing with `componentWillUnmount`. Does it get called? If so, perhaps you can insert some black magic there to minimize the effect, but you'd first need to isolate what specifically is going on before you can hope to solve it.

Comment: I have tested it with other devices just now, It seems that the problem occurs on my personal device only which is Android 7.0.0 T-Mobile Version (Device: Samsung Note 5) . This is perhaps an issue with the device I guess.

Comment: If you want me to test it on my device (Moto Z), let me know

Comment: sure! I will let you know